# Run-time error when passing derived-class pointer C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, segmentation-fault

I am getting a seg fault when trying to add a pointer to an object to a vector in an instance of another object. I am adding multiple pointers to the vector at once and the first one works but the second attempt keeps tossing seg faults.

```
class Observer {
  Observer();
  observe();
};

class Subject {
  std::vector<Observer*> *observers;
  std::string name;

  Subject();
  virtual std::string getName();
  virtual void addObserver(Observer *observer) {
    observers->push_back(observer);
  }
};

class Base : public Subject {
  Base(std::string newName) { name = newName; }
};

class Derivative : public Subject, public Observer {
  float a;
  float b;
  float c;
  Derivative(a, b, c) { this->a = a; this->b = b; this->c = c; }

};

class Board : public Base {
   Base *base;

   Board(std::string newName, Base *newBase) { name = newName; base = newBase; }

   void initializeDerivatives(int start, int end) {
     for (int i = start; i <= end; ++i) {
       addObserver(new Derivative(start, start + 1, start + 2)); //works
       base->addObserver(new Derivative(start, start + 1, start + 2)); //THIS WORKS
       addObserver(new Derivative(start, start + 2, start + 3)); //works
       base->addObserver(new Derivative(start, start + 2, start + 3)); //seg fault here
     }
   }
};

int main() {
  Base myBase("MYBASE");
  Board myBoard("MYBASE", myBase);

  myBoard.initializeDerivatives(1, 10);
}
```

I was getting seg faults earlier when I declared myBoard and myBase as pointers: 
    Base* myBase = new Base("MYBASE");
    Board* myBoard = new Board("MYBASE", myBase);

And I was unsure why that was since I thought using the new operator would actually initialize the instance of the object. Changing it to make the actual objects still allows me to add one pointer to the observers vector, but the second one isn't working. Any thoughts?

Comment: It sounds like the error is in `addDerivative` (since that's the function call that crashes), but you've forgotten to show us that function.

Comment: My fault `addDerivative` should have been `addObserver`

Comment: Board's constructor takes a pointer, but you're passing it the actual object. I wouldn't think that would compile. I wonder what happens if you change it to `Board myBoard("MYBASE", &myBase)`;

Comment: When does the pointer `Subject::observers` get initialized?

Comment: In general, you're using far too many pointers to allocated objects; these rely on correctly written constructors to allocate them, and correctly written destructors (including virtual destructors on most of your classes) to delete them, if you want to avoid memory leaks. You haven't shown us the constructors for `Observer` or `Subject`, but my guess is that `Subject::observers` is not correctly initialised. Changing it to a vector, rather than a pointer to one, is the simplest fix.

Comment: Interesting. So do you fell I should change std::vector<Observer*> *observers; to std::vector<Observer> *observers;? What would be the consequences of that on performance if the vector got very large?

Answer (score 1):

In `class Subject`, you should to change this:

```
std::vector<Observer*> *observers;
```

To this:

```
std::vector<Observer*> observers;
```

As a pointer, your code doesn't show that pointer being initialized anywhere.  If it **is** initialized in the constructor, you likely have a memory leak, since `Subject` doesn't have a destructor.